# Understand Fourier inversion formula

Tags: fourier-series, riemann-zeta, mellin-transform

The "inverse Mellin" transform is used in deriving the explicit Riemann/Von Mangoldt formula for the Chebyshev $\psi$ function.  One comes across the following integrals which are puzzling to me.  c>0.  Can someone help me understand them?

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\exp(k\cdot z)}{z}dz \;=1\;\;\;\forall\; k>0$$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\exp(k\cdot z)}{z}dz \;=0\;\;\;\forall\; k<0$$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\exp(k\cdot z)}{z}dz \;=0.5\;\;\; k=0$$

I'm reading H.M. Edwards' textbook as well as online resources, which call this a Fourier inversion formula.  I'm not completely comfortable with the math for non-periodic Fourier functions, but apparently (I'm guessing) this is a sort of "low pass" filter like the Sinc function which sums up the $a(n)$ terms up to a given value of n for a Dirichlet series.  There was a time in the past when I understood the Sinc function fourier transform.
$$g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(n)}{n^z}$$

Then the Dirichlet series is multiplied by $\frac{x^z}{z} $ and integrated to magically sum up the terms. The prime$'$ on the summation indicates that the last term of the sum must be multiplied by 1/2 when x is an integer, which matches the k=0 and k>0 formulas above.

$$A(x) = \sum_{n<=x}'a(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}g(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz.$$

Comment: For the k=0 case, the $\int\frac{1}{z}dz=\ln(z)$, for the other cases  $\int\frac{\exp(kz)}{z}dz=\ln(z)+f(z)$ where f(z) is entire.  So the k=0 case makes sense as going half around the logarithmic singularity counter clockwise which is $\pi i$.

Comment: For the $k \neq 0$ cases, apply the residue theorem to the contour you get by cutting off at $c \pm i R$ and closing the contour with a semicircle. Take the semicircle in the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} z < c$ for $k > 0$ and in the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} z > c$ for $k < 0$ so that the integral over the semicircle tends to $0$ as $R \to +\infty$. But it is rather unclear to me what is unclear to you. Can you maybe make that clearer?

Comment: @DanielFischer so lets take $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{1-iR}^{1+iR}\frac{\exp(-z)}{z} dz=0$$  How would I show that the integral over the semi-circle tends to 0 as $R \to +\infty$?

Comment: That's essentially a special case of Jordan's lemma, although that is usually formulated for semicircles whose diameter is parallel to the real axis rather than the imaginary axis. One can also use a rectangular contour instead of a semicircle, with vertices $c\pm iR$ and $S \pm iR$. Then $\lvert e^w\rvert = e^{\operatorname{Re} w}$ gives $$\Biggl\lvert \int_{c-iR}^{S-iR} \frac{e^{-z}}{z}\,dz\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{R} \int_c^S e^{-t}\,dt < \frac{e^{-c}}{R}$$ since $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant R$ on that segment, and you have the same estimate for the upper edge. For the right edge, you

Comment: use $\lvert e^{-z}\rvert = e^{-S}$ there to get the estimate $$\Biggl\lvert \int_{S - iR}^{S + iR} \frac{e^{-z}}{z}\,dz\Biggr\rvert \leqslant e^{-S}\int_{-R}^R \frac{dt}{\lvert S + it\rvert} \leqslant 2R\frac{e^{-S}}{S}.$$ So if you let $R,S \to +\infty$ with $S$ not growing too much slower than $R$, you have a bound that tends to $0$. Choosing $S = R$ gives you the bound $2\bigl(\frac{e^{-c}}{R} + e^{-R}\bigr)$, which clearly tends to $0$ as $R \to +\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks Daniel!  Your comments are very helpful!

Comment: @DanielFischer using a square with R=S, the vertical part pretty quickly goes to zero, but the two horizontal segments at $\pm iR$, which sums to an entirely imaginary number, does not go to zero nearly so quickly.  My estimate is $|\frac{2}{\exp(c) R}|$, which seems to be pretty accurate compared to the actual integral when R is a multiple of $\pi$, otherwise it is an overestimate.